# Howto writing a file in plist mode of an array of text dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift4, plist

I work on Swift 4 for XCode 9.3
I want to create a file as done in Objective C with following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com      /DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>ipaddress</key>
    <string>192.168.10.101</string>
    <key>ipport</key>
    <string>12345</string>
    <key>upsname</key>
    <string>S 2000 (Port 1)</string>
    <key>upsport</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>ipaddress</key>
    <string>192.168.10.102</string>
    <key>ipport</key>
    <string>12345</string>
    <key>upsname</key>
    <string>S 3000 (Port 2)</string>
    <key>upsport</key>
    <string>2</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>ipaddress</key>
    <string>192.168.10.103</string>
    <key>ipport</key>
    <string>12345</string>
    <key>upsname</key>
    <string>S 2000 (Port 3)</string>
    <key>upsport</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
```

---

I have made an array of dictionaries printed as follows:

```
[{
ipaddress = "192.168.10.101";
ipport = 12345;
upsname = "S 2000 (Port 1)";
upsport = 1;
}, {
ipaddress = "192.168.10.102";
ipport = 12345;
upsname = "S 3000 (Port 2)";
upsport = 2;
}, {
ipaddress = "192.168.10.103";
ipport = 12345;
upsname = "S 2000 (3)";
upsport = 3;
}]
```

Which function may I use to get a plist file form this array of dictionaries as above
Thanks a lot

Comment: See either `PropertyListSerialization` or `PropertyListEncoder`. I recommend the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4: Adding dictionaries to Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419327/swift-4-adding-dictionaries-to-plist)

Comment: Thank, No need to use PropertyListSerialization class, Just see above What worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Please don't put your answer in your question. Post an actual answer below if you think it will help people.

Comment: Hello, I am new  to stackoverflow.com, and I am sorry to have given a solution to my problem, thinking it would help other. Now I have been banned because I modified my question, giving the solution I had found. I am sorry of this fact, and I removed from the original question  the code I found to write and which worked. Again sorry ! When I wanted to create a real answer, it was not possible!